# How I can post my Facebook comments to my Drupal Site?

Tags: drupal, facebook

How I can post my Facebook comments to my Drupal Site?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these modules:
http://drupal.org/project/fb
http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect
http://drupal.org/project/activitystream